# uiviewcontroller black

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, pushviewcontroller

I've just created a storyboard with few table controllers and one view controller.
Everything works fine until my app push the view controller: it's shown completely black.
I can add map view, image view or whatever, or even nothing (a complete empty view controller), but it's always shown black.

I push it using the the navigation [self.navigationController pushViewController] code line.

This is not happening with table controllers, just with view controllers.

Any suggestion?

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 4E2002.

Thanks in advance,

Samuel

Answer (score 3):

Have you defined your storyboard correctly? This behavior could happen if you failed to properly initialize your storyboard and instantiate your controller from the storyboard. IE, you need to create a UIStoryboard object and need to instantiate your controller by calling 
`[storyboardObject instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"controllerName"];` ...See the thread here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-storyboards

Comment: hi! I tried to instantiate the object as you suggested:
        UIStoryboard *secondStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        MapViewController* mvc = [secondStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"PumpOnMapController"];
        mvc.pump = self.pump;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];

and it worked perfectly... many thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it solved the issue. Perhaps you could accept the answer? Thanks and good luck :)